# Botão contador com Update

Tags: javascript, mysql

Estou com problemas em conseguir fazer um botão em javascript realizar um update sem dar refresh na página, no momento ele não está inserindo no banco e está fazendo refresh hehehe

na index.php

```
<form>
    <button data-id='$futid' class='botao-olho' style='background-color: red;color:#fff'><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>Sim</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //pega-se o botão desejado e arzena na variável

    $(".botao-olho").on("click", function(){ 
        var $this = $(this); 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "update_intencao.php", 
            data: {id: $this.data("id")}, 

        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Update.php

```
<?php     

 include("conexao.php"); 

 $id = $_POST['id']       
 $sql3 = "UPDATE fifa19futdados set intencoes = intencoes + 1 where Futbin_ID = $id";

 mysqli_query($conexao,$sql3);   

 ?>
```

Se não for pedir muito, eu gostaria também que depos da ação ele sumisse o botão e aparecesse uma mensagem, sem refresh.

Obrigado!

Comment: Pegue a instrução sql e execute no banco, veja se funciona. A questão de sumir com o botão sem refresh seria com JavaScript ?

Comment: sim, seria... e eu testei no banco de dados e da certo

Answer (score 0):

Sem muita modificação no seu código e nem verificar o retorno do update, uma opção seria:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".botao-olho").on("click", function(){ 
    var $this = $(this); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "update_intencao.php", 
        data: {id: $this.data("id")}, 
        success: function(response) {
            $this.remove();
        }

    }); 
});
```

Porém é aconselhável que você adote um protocolo de comunicação para tratar erros como JSON. Assim o seu uodate_intencao.php pode devolver respostas estruturadas ao javascript.

Comment: cara eu pego esse id por $futid = $_GET['id']; , eu to desconfiado que não está passando pro update, tem uma forma de eu conferir o retorno do update?